# VB Word Management

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have been trying to create a program to handle events that trigger in Microsoft Word using VB.net. My ultimate goal is to use this program to respond to Word being closed by the user, but when I try to use the `DocumentBeforeClose` or `DocumentBeforeSave` they don't seem to trigger, but I have an event to handle `NewDocument` and that works like it should.

Here is my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents oWord As Word.ApplicationClass
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create a new instance of Word, make it visible, and activate it.
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oWord.Activate()

    'Create a new document.
    oWord.Documents.Add()

    'Release the instance of Word and leave it running.
    oWord = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub oWord_ApplicationEvents2_Event_DocumentBeforeClose(Doc As Word.Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles oWord.ApplicationEvents2_Event_DocumentBeforeClose
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The document is closing.")
End Sub


Private Sub oWord_ApplicationEvents2_Event_DocumentBeforeSave(Doc As Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles oWord.ApplicationEvents2_Event_DocumentBeforeSave
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The document is saving.")
End Sub
'Handler for the Microsoft Word NewDocument event.
'The NewDocument event is fired when a new document is created.

Private Sub oWord_ApplicationEvents2_Event_NewDocument(Doc As Word.Document) Handles oWord.ApplicationEvents2_Event_NewDocument
    'Add some text to the new document.
    With oWord.Selection
        .TypeText("The ")
        With .Font
            .Bold = Word.WdConstants.wdToggle
            .Italic = Word.WdConstants.wdToggle
        End With
        .TypeText("NewDocument ")
        With .Font
            .Bold = Word.WdConstants.wdToggle
            .Italic = Word.WdConstants.wdToggle
        End With
        .TypeText("event handler inserted this text.")
    End With
End Sub
End Class
```

I have my references to Microsoft Office Interop and Microsoft Word Object Library.

I found documentation on .ApplicationEvents2_Event_DocumentBeforeClose Event that states it was not intended to be used from the code, but gives a way to declare and use it so I am unsure if I am using the wrong syntax to use or going the wrong way all together.

Answer (score 1):

**VB.NET**

You could count Word processes via a timer. This will only work well the timer is faster than a user opening and closing another document..

```
Private m_wordProcessCount As Integer = 0
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim processCount As Integer = Process.GetProcessesByName("WinWord").Count()
    If Not processCount < m_wordProcessCount Then
        'a word process has been closed..
        doSomething()
        'update our wordcount
        m_wordProcessCount = processCount
    End If
End Sub
```

**Word Macros**

You could use VBA on the close event of Word..

```
Private Sub Document_Close()   
  Dim strPath As String
  strPath = Dir("C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeProgram\Program.exe")
  'run the external exe
  Shell strPath
End Sub
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211664(v=office.11).aspx